# What is MQ and how is it used in an OpenStack deployment and Java EE applications?

Tags: jakarta-ee, openstack, mq

I have a job interview in a couple days and they are looking for experience with MQ in an OpenStack and Java EE environments.

I have lots of Java and Java EE experience, and I've done some basic OpenStack tutorials, but I don't really understand what "MQ" is and what it's used for.

Can someone give me a good answer:  What is MQ and how is it used in an OpenStack deployment and Java EE applications?

Comment: It's a JMS implementation. Like as that Mojarra is a JSF implementation. And that Weld is a CDI implementation. And that Hibernate is a JPA implementation. And that GlassFish is a Java EE implementation. See it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about IBM MQ , here is the link

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_WebSphere_MQ

Websphere MQ is used for transmitting messages between two distributed system.
Java applications are used for downloading XMS messages from MQ queues and uploading of the same.

```
data.setMsg(msg);
java.io.StringWriter  sw = new StringWriter();
Marshaller.marshal(data, sw);
xmlString = sw.toString();
MessageSender msgsender = new MessageSender();
msgsender.sendMessageToApplication(xmlString);
```

Configuration of Message Queue.

```
 MQEnvironment.hostname  
 MQEnvironment.channel   
 MQEnvironment.port   
 MQ_TOP_QUEUE  
 MQ_QUEUEMANAGER
```

Answer (score 0):

"MQ" means message queueing and is very often used to mean IBM MQ products but may also encompass other products that perform similar functions such as RabbitMQ.
MQ in general is a way to send messages between different platforms and applications.

One of the benefits of MQ is that messages may be sent asynchronously.  It also may be used to help implement a microservices architecture by tying disparate APIs together.